# Using PHP ev class (EvTimer)

Tags: php, class, pecl-ev

Im trying to use [EvTimer](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.evtimer.php) class, part of [PHP ev class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ev.php). I have already installed ev using pecl on my linux machine and it is visible in `phpinfo()`.

I would like to run this sample:

```
// Create and start timer firing after 2 seconds
$w1 = new EvTimer(2, 0, function () {
  echo "2 seconds elapsed\n";
});
Ev::run();
```

But even though i have ev extension installed and enabled, i receive not found error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'EvTimer' not found in /bin/test.php on line 4

Anyone know why it doesnt see the class? Do i have to include it? From where?

Comment: I use 5.5.9, is 5.6.0 a requirement? I don't see it in the class documentation nor in the Requirements chapter.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04, this shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PHP `Ev` Class is `PECL` extension and not bundled with PHP.

Information for installing this PECL extension may be found in the manual chapter titled [Installation of PECL extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php). Additional information such as new releases, downloads, source files, maintainer information, and a CHANGELOG, can be located here: » http://pecl.php.net/package/ev .

another case , open your server php.ini and search for Ev extension and enable it if exists.

Comment: I have it already installed and visible in phpinfo, for installation I used `sudo pecl install ev`. Now it says `pecl/ev is already installed and is the same as the released version 0.2.10`.

Comment: open php.ini and check if its enabled

Comment: It is enabled, in php.ini: `extension="ev.so"`, and phpinfo() at Ev chapter says: `Ev support: enabled, Debug support: disabled, Version: 0.2.10`

Comment: so weird man , maybe the extension is enabled but not working well , can you check use `if ( class_exists('ev') echo 1;` if not exists i think you need to check again ev.so if exists inside the extensions folder

Comment: I've found the problem, PECL updated php.ini only for Apache, not for command line. Thats why I was sure, it is included, because I was opening phpinfo with apache, when I added `extension="ev.so"` also into `/etc/php5/cli` it works, so you were basically right, I was only looking to wrong php.ini, thanks for helping :)